# Add custom character or icon for bulleted list in a Google Presentation?

Tags: google-slides

I would like to put a list into my Google Presentation, and would like to use an icon as the bullet character. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click the bullet list, a list of options opens and you can also draw your own symbol:

[image]

Comment: That does it!  A key this is just selecting the bullets, not the whole text. But now I can use almost any icon - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. You can only use the `List Styles` Google Drive provides you with. To access the styles that are provided go to `Format` -> `List styles`. The image below displays the current list styles available for your use.

[image: example of list styles in Google Drive]

Comment: Can you add a reference to those styles?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I contemplated adding an image earlier, but decided against adding it. I guess I will add it just for clarity and reference though.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of stuff that Google's document editors are missing compared to Microsoft Office products.